# Using for loop containing number as range in template Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to get records count from database, find difference between that count and 4 (`(4 - Applicant.objects.filter(status=1).count())`) and create new elements number of this difference. But I don't know what type should I use for iterating in template: neither `int()` nor `str()` is working for me. Here are my codes:

`views.py`:

```
def index(request): 
    context = {
        'applicants':  Applicant.objects.filter(status=1),
        'empty_cards': 4 - Applicant.objects.filter(status=1).count()
    }
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.POST.get('motivation_letter'):
            Applicant.objects.create(
            name = request.POST.get('name')
            motivation_letter = request.POST.get('motivation_letter'))
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

`index.html`:

```
{% for empty_card in empty_cards %}
<div class="card">
  <div class="img-container">
       <div class="replace-img">
          <i class="fas fa-camera"></i>
          <p>Burada sənin şəklin ola bilər</p>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use range function for this problem like this:

```
'empty_cards': range(4 - Applicant.objects.filter(status=1).count())
```

Generally you must use iterable object and use it in your template.

Comment: If it worked mark this question as answered to help other people with same question can use it. Thank's